# How to test arrow function in React ES6 class

Tags: testing, reactjs, arrow-functions

I used arrow function inside of my React component to avoid binding this context, for example my component look like this;

```
class Comp extends Component {
   _fn1 = () => {}
   _fn2 = () => {}
   render() {
      return (<div></div>);
   }
}
```

How do I test `_fn1` and `_fn2` function in my test cases? Because these kind of function did not associated with React component itself, so when I do

```
 fnStub = sandbox.stub(Comp.prototype, "_fn1");
```

it is not going work, since `_fn` did not bind with `Comp.prototype`. Thus, how can I test those functions in React if I want to create function with arrow syntax? Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide more detail about your testing setup?  It looks like you're using sinon, but what else?  Also, how are you rendering your components for your tests?

Comment: for example:      describe('when clicked', () => {  });

Comment: Did you discover how to do it?

Answer (score 4):

ES6 functions or arrow functions are not added to the class prototype.
However, there are a couple of ways to test them:-

- Test that the functions themselves are called when a suitable event occurs
  ES5 functions exist on the class prototype and something like this is possible:

  ```
  import Component from 'path/to/component';
  import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
  describe(<Component>, () => {
    it('should call handleSubmit', () => {
      const spy = jest.spyOn(Component.prototype, 'handleSubmit');
      const wrapper = shallow(<Component />);
      ...
      //Invoke handleSubmit
      ...
      expect(spy).toBeCalled()
    });
  });
  ```

whereas ES6 functions exist on the instance of the mounted component(you can also use shallow)

```
    import Component from 'path/to/component';
    import { mount } from 'enzyme';
    describe(<Component>, () => {
      it('should call handleSubmit', () => {
        const wrapper = mount(<Component />);
        ...
        const spy = jest.spyOn(wrapper.instance(), 'handleSubmit');
        //update the instance with the new spy
        wrapper.instance().forceUpdate();
        ...
        //invoke handleSubmit
        expect(spy).toBeCalled()
      });
    });
```

- Test their functionality by simulating actions that will invoke these functions and test for the expected behavior

Assuming component content such as:

```
      state = {
        title: 'Current Title'
      };
      updateTitle = (event) => {
        title = event.target.value;
        this.setState({ title });
      }
      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <input type="text" value={this.state.title} onChange={this.updateTitle} />
          <div>
        )
      }
```

`Test`

```
    ...
    wrapper.find('input').simulate('change', {target: {value: 'New title'}});
    expect(wrapper.state().title).toBe('New Title');
    ...
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: It seems to me `wrapper.instance().forceUpdate();` is not required if you spy the method at the proper time.

Answer (score 0):

In general I find it easier to test that these functions have resulted in a correct component state, rather than test the function itself.  For example, here is a component that toggles a state variable when a button is clicked:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
    state = {
        toggle: false
    }

   _fn1 = () => {
       this.setState(previousState => ({
           toggle: !previousState.toggle
       });
   }

   render() {
      const { toggle } = this.state;

      return (
          <button onClick={this.clickHandler}>
              Turn me {toggle ? 'on' : 'off'}
          </button>
      );
   }
}
```

My preferred approach here would be to test the component as a whole, i.e. the "unit" of the unit test is the component.  The test would therefore find the button, simulate a click, and ensure that the correct text is shown.  This may not be a textbook unit test, but it achieves the goal of testing the component.

Using sinon/chai/mocha/enzyme:

```
describe('My Component', () => {
    it('alternates text display when the button is clicked', () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent />);

        expect(wrapper).to.have.text('Turn me off');

        wrapper.find('button').simulate('click');

        expect(wrapper).to.have.text('Turn me on');
    });
});
```